# How can i pass HTML dropdown value to JSTL sql:query?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have seen similar questions on SO but the answers weren't that convincing.

My program needs to load the content based on the drop down value. I've used JSTL sql:query, so i need to pass the drop down value to the sql:query tag.

my code

```
 Select Book Type <br>
<select name="bookdropdown">
     <option value="Crime">Crime </option>
     <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
     <option value="Mystery">Mystery</option>
</select>
```

```
//SQL Datasource configuration code


       <sql:query var="listBooks"   dataSource="${myDS}">
           SELECT * FROM Books WHERE type = ?
            <sql:param value="${bookdropdown}" />
              </sql:query>
```

Is there a direct way to load content i want based on the drop down value like i've tried? or should i go through the servlet passing parameters with the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The html code works on the client side in the browser. The JSTL code works on the server side. In order to pass the selected item to the server side you need to submit the form and you can access the form's content as a parameter: `${param.bookdropdown}`. I would not start mixing ajax with this old technology.

```
   <sql:query var="listBooks"   dataSource="${myDS}">
       SELECT * FROM Books WHERE type = ?
        <sql:param value="${param.bookdropdown}" />
          </sql:query>
```

Comment: you suggest that i should go through the servlet in order to load content based on the drop down value?

Comment: I do not suggest such thing, since I have no idea what you are trying to achieve beyond this question. I would definitely think about if it is feasible to replace JSTL completely. But such questions are beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: *"replace JSTL completely"* Correction: "replace JSTL `sql` (and `xml`) tag libraries". They are indeed discouraged since 2001 (see also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), but please don't overgeneralize `c`, `fmt` and `fn` taglibs along, they still have their value to the day.